# Is Global Temporary Table space allocation occurs in session start?

Tags: oracle, session, temp-tables, temporary

I found this information in from [Donald Burleson](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_gtt_global_temporary_tablespace_troubleshooting_debugging.htm)=>
Note that all global temporary table rows go directly to the PGA work area before they spill out into the TEMP tablespace, and Oracle does not create a temporary segment if an operation can be performed in memory. However, if PGA RAM allocation is exhausted, then the database automatically allocates a temporary segment on disk.
Is this mean that space allocation not occur in the session start which used first PGA ?
Needs experts opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(In a typical configuration) each session that connects to the database gets their *own* PGA memory. Each of those sessions can hence have their own data for a global temporary table (even though that table is defined only once).

```
Session 1

SQL> create global temporary table GTT
  2   ( x int, y int )
  3  on commit preserve rows;

Table created.

SQL> insert into gtt values (1,2);

1 row created.

Session 2

SQL> select * from gtt;

no rows selected
```

Each session has their own "instantiation" of the table, and their data goes into the memory area for that session alone.  So above, session 1 will be consuming some bytes of PGA for their 2 rows, and session 2 will be consuming no bytes for their empty table.

In either case, the data goes into memory until such point as the database decides that too much PGA **for that session** is being consumed. Then *that sessions* data will start to consume a temporary segment on disk. Lets say the limit was "1 row" (obviously its more), then in the above example, session 1 would start to dump to disk and session 2 would not.

Hope that help clarify things.

Comment: happy to help. A good place to search for answers is asktom.oracle.com as well

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding  the question is asking when the session started what happened to the Global temporary tables, It didn't say start session and transaction.
When you login to your account Oracle generate new session (SID) and Global Temporary tables will be empty after logoff or commit/rollback, So I don't think it allocate space after login only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).